# Local area network visit node server with webpack-dev-server

Tags: node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I build a app with Express, React and Webpack. I used webpack-dev-server and react-hot-loader to live-loding.

The Express server is on port 3000 and the webpack-dev-server servers files on `localhost:8080`.

Now I want to visit the app from another client in the local area network. I can visit the `development machine IP:3000`, but can not access the `localhost:8080`

My `webpack.config.dev.js` file is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/client/entry',
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/js',
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/public/js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env": {
                BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true)
            }
        })
    ],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.css']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'react-hot',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
                compact: false
            },
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, ]
    }
}
```

and the HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">{{ content|safe }}</div>
  <script src="http://localhost:8080/public/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the webpack-dev-server is

```
import WebpackDevServer from "webpack-dev-server";
import webpack from "webpack";
import config from "../../webpack.config.dev";

var server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
  // webpack-dev-server options
  publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  stats: { colors: true },
  headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" }
});

server.listen(8080, "localhost", function() {});
```

I hope I can keep live-reloading on my local development machine and other computer or mobile phone can access the server and static files via `development machine IP:3000`

I am not familiar with webpack. I just followed some tutorials to build the development environment.

How should I change the config?

Comment: So, you are serving the HTML file on port `3000` with Express and the `app.js` on port `8080` with webpack-dev-server, right? And are both servers in the same machine? Why not serve everything with one server?

Comment: @dreyescat Because the webpack-dev-server works like that. I tried webpack-dev-middleware which provide the bundled file on one server but the hot reloading works bad with it because the server started by nodemon will auto restart when file changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to accept connections from other machines other than localhost you need to configure the `hostname` parameter in your `server.listen` call. In your case you are just allowing connections on `"localhost"`:

```
server.listen(8080, "localhost", function() {});
```

For example, to accept connections on any address just remove that parameter:

```
server.listen(8080, function() {});
```

Check [`server.listen`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. But I think there's still a problem with the `<script src="http://localhost:8080/public/js/app.js"></script>` in HTML file. When I visit the server from another machine, the `localhost` represent the machine which sent request but not the server so I can't access the js file.

Comment: What happens if you just remove `http://localhost:8080/` from your `script` like this `<script src="public/js/app.js"></script>` and try to load page from port `8080` instead of `3000`?

Comment: The webpack-dev-server serves the bundled file in memory. There's no such file in disk so I can't visit it from port 3000